# Hohmann transfer: question on vessel orientation

Tags: orbital-motion, satellites

I am looking at the Hohmann transfer and I would like to apply it to KSP. So I'm trying to see the different formulas needed to calculate the $\Delta V$ needed to change the orbit (only the orbit, not the plane). I also need to find the orientation needed to be tangent to the orbit. For the example, we will say that it is elliptical, that allows to be more general.

I looked a little bit at what I needed and to find the orientation, here's what I would like to do:

1. Calculation of the eccentricity: for that, I apply the formula:
   $$e = \frac{r_a - r_p}{r_a + r_p}$$, this is the simplest since I can easily find the apoapsis $a$ and the periapsis $p$ and the radius $r$ ($r_a$ is the radius at the apoapsis, etc...), but if not I can also calculate the eccentricity with:
   $$e = \sqrt{(1 + \frac{2\cdot\epsilon \cdot h^2}{\mu^2}}$$ but for that I have to calculate the specific angular momentum which remains a bit harder ($h$) and the specific orbital energy ($\epsilon$).
2. In my ellipse, I know that the planet, here the Earth, will be one of the two foci of the ellipse, so I can easily deduce the second one by calculating the distance between $F$ and $F'$ with: $$d(O, F') = a/e$$ ($a$ is the apoapsis, $e$ the eccentricity), so the distance $$d(F, F') = 2\cdot d(O, F')$$.
3. To find the tangent at the point $M$ of the ellipse, we need to find the perpendicular to the bisector of the angle $FMF'$ passing through $M$. Since I can easily get the coordinates of the point $M$, center on Earth, I can calculate $d(M, F)$ and consequently, obtain $d(M, F')$ quite easily, which would allow me by applying A-Khawarizmi to find my angle, and thus obtain a bisector.

However I have doubts about my method (especially on the 3rd point), could someone tell me if there are some points to review/improve/correct?